# pandas: removing multiple str from a str

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, replace, python-re

I am trying to remove a list of str from a column value like:

```
char_lst = ['1.', '1)', '2.', '2)', '3.', '3)']  # so on with the digit format
```

I tried:

```
import re
df['X'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('|'.join(replace_char), '', re.escape(x))).astype(str)
```

but it gives me error:

```
re.error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['2)A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'D', 'H', 'I1.', 'J3)']})

char_lst = ['1.', '1)', '2.', '2)', '3.', '3)']

df['X'] = df['X'].str.replace("|".join(re.escape(x) for x in char_lst),'', regex=True)
print  (df)
    X
0   A
1   B
2   C
3   A
4   D
5   E
6   F
7   D
8   H
9   I
10  J
```

EDIT: If need remove numbers with `.` or `)` after digits use:

```
df['X'] = df['X'].str.replace("\d+[\.\)]",'', regex=True)
```

Comment: what if there is `4.` and `4)` as well? how can I make the list dynamic or use a better approach?

Comment: @Jlow - so need `df['X'] = df['X'].str.replace("\d+[\.\)]",'', regex=True)` ?